# How to use spring validation for ajax request?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Now I have following controller methods:

```
@ModelAttribute("multipartFileWrapper")
public MultipartFileWrapper createEmployeeModel() {
   return new MultipartFileWrapper();
}

public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@Validated MultipartFileWrapper file, BindingResult result, Principal principal, HttpSession session) {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
           ....
```

and following bean wrapper for validation:

```
@Component
public class MultipartFileWrapper {
    @Extensions(imageFormats = {".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp"}, videoFormats = {".mp4"})
    MultipartFile multipartFile;

    public MultipartFile getMultipartFile() {
        return multipartFile;
    }

    public void setMultipartFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        this.multipartFile = multipartFile;
    }
}
```

Extensions annotation declaration:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ExtensionValidator.class})
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
public @interface Extensions {

    String message() default "file format is not acceptable";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * Specify accepted content types.
     *
     * @return accepted extensions
     */
    String[] imageFormats();
    String[] videoFormats();
}
```

and validator:

```
public class ExtensionValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Extensions, MultipartFile> {

    private String[] acceptedExtensions;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Extensions extensions) {
        //logic
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //logic
     }
}
```

and following jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST"  action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageUploadForm" commandName="multipartFileWrapper" >
 ....
</form:form>
```

Now I need to validate file which send using ajax.

ajax call:

```
$(".file").on("change", function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('data');
        if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== false) {
            var image=this.files[0];
            var terminalId=data.replace("file", "");
            var postData = new FormData();
            postData.append('image',image);
            postData.append('terminalId',terminalId);

            $("div[data='errors"+terminalId+"']").hide();
         $.ajax({
             url: "<c:url value='/owner/terminals/uploadImage'/>",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             data: postData
         })
         .success(function(data) {
            ...
          })
         .fail(function() {
                ...
              });


        } 

    });
```

How can I make it?  Is it possible to reuse my current code?

Comment: ajax is just another HTTP request, i.e. if you make "same request with ajax", it should work. what specifically is the problem? how to make such request from client or your validation is not working on server or something else?

Comment: problem with how to make "same request with ajax"

Comment: I think that I can somehow witing code like this:  validator.validate(myWrapper)

Comment: as I see that you already have some ajax, where is the problem? can you 1. compare "normal post" request and "new ajax" request in your browser net console to see if e.g. url, post params etc looks the same. 2. does the request hits your server controller as expected (add some log or debug). 3. is there any special error response returned for your ajax call?

Comment: I have not error but controller accepts MultipartFileWrapper now. Spring cannot apply his magic to wrap object to wrapper. I want to know best practise